# How should I deal with nested conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a series of nested conditional checks and I am trying to come up with a clean solution and avoid `if{}else{}` hell as much as possible. Please see the example code as a demonstration of what I am trying to achieve.

In summary, I have two objects, `CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT` and `CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE` and I am trying to go through a nested age check:

```
first check the days,
    then check hours,
       then check minutes,
           then check seconds
```

The idea is that, the moment we reach a greater value, for example, days are equal, then we move on to hours and if we catch a greater hour value there, we end the check.

Please see the example for further info.

```js
const CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT = {
  days: 3,
  hours: 6,
  minutes: 15,
  seconds: 57
}

const CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE = {
  days: 3,
  hours: 5,
  minutes: 14,
  seconds: 57
}

function timeDiff(ageObj1, ageObj2) {
  console.log('days_limit', ageObj1.days, '?', 'days_age', ageObj2.days);
  // old: days
  document.getElementById("current_days").innerHTML = ageObj2.days;
  if (ageObj1.days < ageObj2.days) {
    console.log('old (days)');
    document.getElementById("current_days").classList.add("red");
    return true;
  } else {
   // equal: days
    if (ageObj1.days == ageObj2.days) {
     document.getElementById("current_hours").innerHTML = ageObj2.hours;
      console.log('\tnext: hours');
      console.log('\thours_limit', ageObj1.hours, '?', 'hours_age', ageObj2.hours);
      if (ageObj1.hours < ageObj2.hours) {
        console.log('\told (hours)');
        document.getElementById("current_hours").classList.add("red");
        return true;
      } else {
        // equal: hours
        if (ageObj1.hours == ageObj2.hours) {
          document.getElementById("current_minutes").innerHTML = ageObj2.minutes;
          console.log('\t\tnext (minutes)');
          console.log('\t\tminutes_limit', ageObj1.minutes, '?', 'minutes_age', ageObj2.minutes);
          if (ageObj1.minutes < ageObj2.minutes) {
            // old: minutes
            console.log('\t\told (minutes)');
            document.getElementById("current_minutes").classList.add("red");
            return true;
          } else {
            // equal: minutes
            if (ageObj1.minutes == ageObj2.minutes) {
              document.getElementById("current_seconds").innerHTML = ageObj2.seconds;
              console.log('\t\t\tnext (seconds)');
              console.log('\t\t\tseconds_limit', ageObj1.seconds, '?', 'seconds_age', ageObj2.seconds);
              if (ageObj1.seconds < ageObj2.seconds) {
                console.log('\t\t\told (seconds)');
                document.getElementById("current_seconds").classList.add("red");
                return true;
              } else {
                console.log('\t\t\tNOT old (seconds)');
                document.getElementById("current_seconds").classList.add("blue");
                return false;
              }
            } else {
              console.log('\t\tNOT old (minutes)');
              return false;
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log('\tNOT old (hours)');
          document.getElementById("current_hours").classList.add("blue");
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('NOT old (days)');
      document.getElementById("current_days").classList.add("blue");
      return false;
    }
  }
}

// Populate Limits
var limit_fields = document.querySelectorAll(".limit");
for(i=0; i < limit_fields.length; i++){
    //console.log('--->', i)
        let id = limit_fields[i].id.split("_")[1];
        let val = CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT[id]
        //console.log('\tid:', id, 'val:', val);
        limit_fields[i].innerHTML = val;
    }

// Evaluate Age
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = timeDiff(CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT, CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE) ? "old" : "up to date";
```

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: black;
}

.tg .value {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .current {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .current.red {
  color: red;
}

.tg .current.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.tg .limit {
  color: #85929E;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .header {
  background-color: #ffffc7;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .item {
  background-color: #ffffc7;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .empty {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .result {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #ffce93;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .output {
  background-color: #FDEBD0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 265px">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 92px">
    <col style="width: 92px">
    <col style="width: 92px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="empty"></th>
    <th class="header">CURRENT</th>
    <th class="header">LIMITS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">DAYS</td>
    <td id="current_days" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_days" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">HOURS</td>
    <td id="current_hours" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_hours" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">MINUTES</td>
    <td id="current_minutes" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_minutes" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">SECONDS</td>
    <td id="current_seconds" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_seconds" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="result">RESULT</td>
    <td id="output" class="output" colspan="2">up to date</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So as you can see, the conditional execution ends once it is clear that the `hours` are enough to determine the age.

Please change the values in the `CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE` to test it.

--- UPDATE ---

There were multiple solutions so thanks to everyone for the help. Unfortunately I will have to pick up one of the answer to close the question.

Here is a demo of the solution:

[image]

Comment: Do some research on [`else if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Description). That will reduce some nesting.

Comment: I think you're looking for simply `A && B && C`. Then after evaluating that, set the color accordingly.

Comment: Sure. I still get excited and seek closure. But you are absolutely right. I will take this into account next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So another possibility is to create something like a UNITS array, which contains simply the text representation of each property of your time-ish object, in the order you want to handle them. Then, simply use a while loop to iterate over that UNITS array, and update each DOM element in turn.

```js
const CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT = {
  days: 3,
  hours: 6,
  minutes: 15,
  seconds: 57
}, CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE = {
  days: 3,
  hours: 5,
  minutes: 17, 
  seconds: 57
  
}, UNITS = ["days", "hours","minutes","seconds"]

function timeDiff(ageObj1, ageObj2) {
  // We create a flag, and an index to iterate over our UNITS array
  let unitsIndex = 0;
  
  // if the upToDate flag is TRUE
  while(unitsIndex <= UNITS.length){
    // We'll use template literals to create the IDs
    currentEl = document.getElementById(`current_${UNITS[unitsIndex]}`),
    limitEl = document.getElementById(`limit_${UNITS[unitsIndex]}`);

    console.log(UNITS[unitsIndex],ageObj1[UNITS[unitsIndex]],ageObj2[UNITS[unitsIndex]]) 
    // Update the content of the current and limit elements    
    currentEl.innerHTML = ageObj2[UNITS[unitsIndex]];
    limitEl.innerHTML = ageObj1[UNITS[unitsIndex]];
    
    // Here we check: is our limit unit less than our current?
    if (ageObj1[UNITS[unitsIndex]] < ageObj2[UNITS[unitsIndex]]) {
      /**
       * In this case, our current has exceeded our limit. Bad bad bad.
       **/
       console.info(`The current ${UNITS[unitsIndex]} is stale.`)
      currentEl.classList.add("red");  
      return false;
    } else if(ageObj1[UNITS[unitsIndex]] > ageObj2[UNITS[unitsIndex]]){
      /**
       * In this case, our limit is  more than a full unit greater than our current. goodgoodgood.
       **/
       console.info(`The current ${UNITS[unitsIndex]} is more than a full unit to the good.`)
      return true;
    }
         
    //increment our UNITS array pointer
    unitsIndex++;
  }
  // if we get here, then all the DHMS have passed --  we can return true
  return true;
}

// Populate Limits
var limit_fields = document.querySelectorAll(".limit");
for(i=0; i < limit_fields.length; i++){
    //console.log('--->', i)
        let id = limit_fields[i].id.split("_")[1];
        let val = CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT[id]
        //console.log('\tid:', id, 'val:', val);
        limit_fields[i].innerHTML = val;
    }

// Evaluate Age
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = timeDiff(CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT, CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE) ? "up to date" : "old";
```

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: black;
}

.tg .value {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .current {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .current.red {
  color: red;
}

.tg .current.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.tg .limit {
  color: #85929E;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .header {
  background-color: #ffffc7;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .item {
  background-color: #ffffc7;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .empty {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .result {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #ffce93;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .output {
  background-color: #FDEBD0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 265px">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 92px">
    <col style="width: 92px">
    <col style="width: 92px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="empty"></th>
    <th class="header">CURRENT</th>
    <th class="header">LIMITS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">DAYS</td>
    <td id="current_days" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_days" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">HOURS</td>
    <td id="current_hours" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_hours" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">MINUTES</td>
    <td id="current_minutes" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_minutes" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">SECONDS</td>
    <td id="current_seconds" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_seconds" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="result">RESULT</td>
    <td id="output" class="output" colspan="2">up to date</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I'm using Template literals to define the id on each iteration:

```
`current_${UNITS[unitIndex] }`

By doing so, I don't have to hard-code the id every time. As long as I can trust the prefixes, this works pretty well. And it seems to get rid of a lot of your if statements, simply by running them each sequentially.

EDIT: I'm an idiot. So there are two branches to your if statement (well, three). First, if the current is beyond the limit, return false immediately, as that is OLD. Second, if the limit is more than a full unit greater than the current, immediately return true, as the current is well within its limit. Third, if they are equal, loop on to the next unit. If all units process and we fall through the while loop, then  they are the same exact. Weird, but still good. Code updated to reflect the SECOND case.
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the help. I think there are some issues with this code. When `hour_limit=6` and the `hour_value=5` the loop should end as this is enough to satisfy the `up-to-data` condition. Instead it keeps running and compares against the minutes.

Comment: OK, so is this the spec: If the current has exceeded the limit in this unit, it's old. If the limit exceeds the current by more than a full unit, we're GOOD. If they are equal, keep looping. Sound right? Check this: https://codepen.io/snowmonkey/pen/gqJdKp?editors=0010

Comment: Yes. I can confirm this is working: https://media.giphy.com/media/lYiO777p1cKPT3jkrZ/giphy.gif

Comment: Sweet. Glad it worked out. If this works for you, don't forget to mark it as a solution, so others know you're set. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only way, to transform nested conditions, to a linear representation of the code, is to move particels of single conditions into a function and use `some` for have a short circuit to exit the run. While you need to return a value, you need to store this flag, because the return value of `some` does not work for this.

The advanatge of this approach is to add more or less infinite conditions, break them as wanted and return a boolean value for further operations.

The disadvantage is, you need to have a look for data, the nested structure and an understanding, that the next condition/function is called until the function returnes `true`, despite the value of the flag.

```js
const CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT = {
  days: 3,
  hours: 6,
  minutes: 15,
  seconds: 57
}

const CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE = {
  days: 3,
  hours: 5,
  minutes: 14,
  seconds: 57
}

function timeDiff(ageObj1, ageObj2) {
    var flag;
    [
        () => {
            document.getElementById("current_days").innerHTML = ageObj2.days;
            if (ageObj1.days < ageObj2.days) {
                document.getElementById("current_days").classList.add("red");
                return flag = true;
            }
        },
        () => {
            if (ageObj1.days == ageObj2.days) {
                document.getElementById("current_hours").innerHTML = ageObj2.hours;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("current_days").classList.add("blue");
                flag = false;
                return true;
            }
        },
        () => {
            if (ageObj1.hours < ageObj2.hours) {
                document.getElementById("current_hours").classList.add("red");
                return flag = true;
            }
        },
        () => {
            if (ageObj1.hours == ageObj2.hours) {
                document.getElementById("current_minutes").innerHTML = ageObj2.minutes;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("current_hours").classList.add("blue");
                flag = false;
                return true;
            }
        },
        () => {
            if (ageObj1.minutes < ageObj2.minutes) {
                document.getElementById("current_minutes").classList.add("red");
                return flag = true;
            }
        },
        () => {
            if (ageObj1.minutes == ageObj2.minutes) {
                document.getElementById("current_seconds").innerHTML = ageObj2.seconds;
            } else {
                flag = false;
                return true;
            }
        },
        () => {
            if (ageObj1.seconds < ageObj2.seconds) {
                document.getElementById("current_seconds").classList.add("red");
                return flag = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("current_seconds").classList.add("blue");
                flag = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    ].some(fn => fn());
    return flag;
}


// Populate Limits
var limit_fields = document.querySelectorAll(".limit");
for(i=0; i < limit_fields.length; i++){
    //console.log('--->', i)
        let id = limit_fields[i].id.split("_")[1];
        let val = CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT[id]
        //console.log('\tid:', id, 'val:', val);
        limit_fields[i].innerHTML = val;
    }

// Evaluate Age
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = timeDiff(CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT, CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE) ? "old" : "up to date";
```

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: black;
}

.tg .value {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .current {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .current.red {
  color: red;
}

.tg .current.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.tg .limit {
  color: #85929E;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .header {
  background-color: #ffffc7;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .item {
  background-color: #ffffc7;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .empty {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .result {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #ffce93;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .output {
  background-color: #FDEBD0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 265px">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 92px">
    <col style="width: 92px">
    <col style="width: 92px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="empty"></th>
    <th class="header">CURRENT</th>
    <th class="header">LIMITS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">DAYS</td>
    <td id="current_days" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_days" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">HOURS</td>
    <td id="current_hours" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_hours" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">MINUTES</td>
    <td id="current_minutes" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_minutes" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">SECONDS</td>
    <td id="current_seconds" class="value current">-</td>
    <td id="limit_seconds" class="value limit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="result">RESULT</td>
    <td id="output" class="output" colspan="2">up to date</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But you could take an array with keys and perform the until some parts returns `true`.

```
function timeDiff(ageObj1, ageObj2) {
    var flag;

    ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'].some((key, index, keys) => {
        var nextKey = keys[index + 1],
            element = document.getElementById("current_" + key),
            nextElement = document.getElementById("current_" + nextKey);

        element.innerHTML = ageObj2[key];
        if (ageObj1[key] < ageObj2[key]) {
            element.classList.add("red");
            return flag = true;
        }
        if (ageObj1[key] == ageObj2[key] && nextKey) {
            nextElement.innerHTML = ageObj2[nextKey];
        } else {
            element.classList.add("blue");
            flag = false;
            return true;
        }
    });

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work and provides an alternative approach. I need to properly study your solution to understand what the code does. Thanks.

Comment: I am curious to know the reasons for down voting this answer.

Comment: I'm upvoting, for two reasons: one, I see no reason to downvote a valid answer, and two, mad respect for Nina and her keen insights.

Comment: I really appreciate this, both answers are great. I had to choose one though :(. Once again thank you very much, this was extremely educational. I hope this question and the answers function as a mini case-study and others can benefit as well.

Comment: This seems to be missing a closing brace (and the indentation doesn't work out either). Also, what good is that `flag`?

Comment: @Bergi, it holds the return value for later `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = timeDiff(CACHE_FILE_AGE_LIMIT, CACHE_FILE_CURRENT_AGE) ? "old" : "up to date";`

Comment: Yes, there are some typos, so I cleaned it up and uploaded this solution here: https://codepen.io/symbolix/pen/yZWRjQ